# Import / Export database from Azure SQL Server using AD authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm getting an error when attempting to either export or import SQL Server databases through the Azure Portal using an user account that is in the SQL Server AD administrators group.

As you can see I have an AD group attached to the SQL Server and I am a member in that group.

[image]

When I attempt to export or import a database from that server using my user credentials (and selecting Active Directory in the Authentication Type), I get the following error:

> Failed to export the database: TheNameOfTheDatabase.
>   ErrorCode: 400
>   ErrorMessage: There was an error that occurred during this operation : 'Error encountered during the service operation.
>   Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unable to authenticate request; '

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes services Azure portal does not work as expected temporarily. As a workaround, try to export the database using the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio and the feature named “Export a Data-Tier Application”.

Try also using SqlPackage utility.

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:Export /tf:testExport.bacpac /scs:"Data Source=apptestserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyDB;" /ua:True /tid:"apptest.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Make sure “Allow Access to Azure services” is ON on the firewall rules.

Comment: i'm actually running this code from powershell using the New-AzSqlDatabaseImport command as oppose to the portal. i get the same issue hence why i used the portal as a demonstration in this question. i'm actually wondering if the issue is to do with the fact our active directory is configured to use MFA for login and the error message just isn't indicating that.

Comment: MFA could indeed be a factor here.

Comment: SSMS and sqlpackage both support MFA